# bubushka keeps asking me for a uri? under apt source section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, babushka

I'm using Debian 'testing' which should be based on Wheezy. I've tried adding the required fields as per rob holland's changes in:

http://proxy.nwang.info/github.com/robholland/babushka

But I still get the question at apt source time:

```
sudo ruby /home/map7/.babushka/bootstrap/bin/babushka.rb babushka
babushka {
  up to date.babushka {
    repo clean.babushka {
      installed.babushka {
        Where would you like babushka installed [/usr/local/babushka]? 
        ruby {
          'ruby' & 'irb' run from /usr/bin.
          ✓ ruby is 1.8.7, which is >= 1.8.6.
        } ✓ ruby
        git {
          'git >= 1.6' is missing.
          git.managed {
            apt {
              package manager {
                'apt-get' runs from /usr/bin.
              } ✓ package manager
              apt source {
                uri? 
                That was blank. uri?
```

What should I put in the uri section?
Does babushka work on Debian testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't been checking stackoverflow for babushka questions. I'll make a point of it from now on.

Is this still an issue? The apt source stuff has been refactored a bit recently, so it's worth retrying this on the latest release.

Cheers